# Should I take a wight gainer without doing workout?

Tags: weight-gain

I am working guy, I want to increase my weight, but the thing is I won't be able to do workout due to the work. But I have dumbbells and iron bar for regular exercise. Should I take a weight gainer without going to a gym ? Please help me out to increase my weight.

Comment: By "I want to increase my weight", do you mean add muscle, or, pure body weight?  And, is your current weight "normal" for your body size?

Comment: #rrirower, I want increase pure body weight, and my current weight is less than it's required.

Comment: Can you provide specifics?  Less than required for what?  Are you otherwise healthy?

Comment: my height is 5'6", and weight is 52 KG, otherwise i am healthy. Also did report but there is no health issues, just short of vitamins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are a hard training athlete, I would caution about using weight gain powders.  They typically contain more calories than you need, and, people tend to use them to substitute for a meal because it is much easier to make a quick drink than prepare a nutritious meal.  They can also be quite expensive.  Instead, try to increase your calories by eating a sensible diet.  There are plenty of posts on this forum where people have asked how to gain weight with proper nutrition.  I would also track my current calories in a food journal so that you can increase them gradually.  Good luck and don't expect results over night.

Comment: #rrirower, Thanks. I will be waiting for that.

Comment: If i would take the lesser scoop than its required, is it help me out? Give some tips.

Comment: Just eat more real food.